# Axes3Dの座標軸を等間隔にしたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

現在、 Python 環境上で次のようにして Axes3D を利用しています。

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

ところが、この Axes3D は座標軸の座標目盛間隔を自動的に決めてしまうので、表示されたものの形が変わってしまいます。

そこで、 Axes3D は座標軸の座標目盛間隔を等間隔にしたいと思っています。
どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際に目盛間隔が変わってしまう具体例（コードなど）を追記して頂けると、回答がつきやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Qiitaの　[matplotlibで3次元プロットする際に3軸のスケールを揃える](https://qiita.com/ae14watanabe/items/71f678755525d8088849)　の記事が参考にしてはどうでしょう。